# Is there a good practice limit to amount of catches in one try block?

Tags: java, exception

I'm writing a REST client which validates an incoming request, maps to object, then sends a request on to another REST producer.

In my validation I validate a number of required fields to build this request.  For each failure I've created and thrown a custom exception.  That is if one isn't thrown by the validation automatically (`LocalDate.parse(myDate)` for example, which throws `DateTimeParseException()`).

My question is, in the method in which I am handling these multiple exceptions, I have 6 catch blocks:

```
public ResponseEntity postSomething(@RequestBody final Request body) {
        ResponseEntity<Response> response;
        try {
            response= myIngestionService.callIngestionInterface(body);
        }
        catch (EmptyResponseException e) {
            //LOG error and return an error response with error message info
        }
        catch (DocumentNotValidBase64EncodingException e) {
            //LOG error and return an error response with error message info
        }
        catch (HighLowPercentagesOutOfRangeException e) {
            //LOG error and return an error response with error message info
        }
        catch (IdOutOfRangeException e) {
            //LOG error and return an error response with error message info
        }
        catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            //LOG error and return an error response with error message info
        }
        catch (AnotherException e) {
            //LOG error and return an error response with error message info
        }
        //return response
    }
```

This seems maybe a little excessive to me, is it?  I have a niggling feeling that at this point I should maybe be going back and rethinking my validation, but not sure.

Comment: Either catch `Exception` (the parent class), or use a multi-catch. Why do you need six separate catch blocks?

Comment: It all those cases are all yours, may I suggest two refactorings (not mutually exclusive) : have them all inherit from a base class "YourValidationException", that you can catch in a single block. And/or have only one exception class, and create an Enum like ValidationFailure with values such as DateTime, IdRange, Base64, ... You might end up testing instanceof (or switch on the enum) instead of having multiple blocks, not sure which is "best", but you can do that using non-exception related patterns.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch maybe for different custom messages to return

Comment: Yes @jhamon that is why :).

Comment: Thanks @GPI I will check this out, this sounds good.

Comment: Is there any specific reason your required fields validation logic is exception driven?  Using exceptions gratuitously is where you lose the performance. You can simply write a validation handler, pass object to it, aggregate errors and just throw one exception with appropriate error(s) array. Exceptions are expensive because of filling the stack trace and then unwinding the stack.

Remember exception is an unexpected event which occurs during the execution of a program at run time and it disrupts the flow of the program. In your case, validation is part of the logic.

Comment: You only lose performance on the cases that fail validation, surely.  Why does it matter to make failures work efficiently?

Comment: @another-dave: i think the performance thing is not the main issue, it's about not being able to send back multiple validation errors. the OP has limited the options by committing to using exceptions for this.

Comment: @NathanHughes this is a good point actually, it just crossed my mind.